# How should I edit strings across many instances of the same html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I've got this code below, with different data, repeated over 10 times on the page I am working on:

HTML:

```
    <div class="kpaGraph">
        <p>Target: 43%</p>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="bar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="kpaBottom">
      <div class="strong">
        <p>311</p>
      </div>
      <div class="weak">
        <p>number of teachers trained</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I want to alter the number in `div.strong p` (311) based on the number in `div.kpaGraph p` (43%) in the same manner across all instances of this code with Javascript/ jQuery. What is the cleanest way to do this? Should I select all `$('div.kpaGraph p')` and then use `each()` Or should I create a function and run it on all of them?

Thanks!

Comment: You should select all `$('div.kpaGraph p')` and then use `each()` AND pass `each` a anonymous) function to make it work.

Comment: So when the `kpaGraph` target value is changed the value in `kpaBottom` below should change but only for the one right below that `kpaGraph`? Or when it is changed all 10 change too?

Comment: Only for the one right below it, for each instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to find the proper element in conjuntion with an `.each()` on `$('div.kpaGraph p')`:

```
$(this).parent().next('div.kpaBottom').find('div.strong p')
```

For example, using the following will take the value in the kpaGraph p node and append it to the p node in the following kpaBottom node:

```
$('div.kpaGraph p').each(function () {
    $(this).parent().next('div.kpaBottom').find('div.strong p').html('foo');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8ZrSE/)**

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways.

You can use "next".

```
$('.kpaGraph').each(function(){
   var $kpaStrong = $(this).next('.kpaBottom .strong p');//this is the elm that has 311
});
```

Or you have to somehow create a relation between them so you know they go together, like a common parent.

```
<div class="kpaWr">
    <div class="kpaGraph">
        <p>Target: 43%</p>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="bar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="kpaBottom">
        <div class="strong">
            <p>311</p>
        </div>
        <div class="weak">
            <p>number of teachers trained</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then with jQuery you can select it like so:

```
$('.kpaGraph').each(function(){
   var $kpaStrong = $(this).closest('.kpaWr').find('.kpaBottom .strong p');//this is the elm that has 311
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might be pretty clean too:

```
$("div.strong p").text(function(index, text){
    return $(this).closest("div.kpaBottom").prev("div.kpaGraph").find("p").text();
});
```

That would change the text to `Target: 43%` in your example.